# URL token authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, url, authentication

I'm looking for a way in which I can send out a user an email with a url that will log them into their user. This doesn't even necessarily have to expire. I have found tons of material on sessions however this is not what I'm after. What I need is this:

- User submits something to the website
- They have an account made in the background
- An email is sent out containing a link "site.com/&token=foobar23124123"
- The user can log in using that link (optional: for the next week)

Is there something out there that I'm missing that would help me or would I have to implement my own solution? Could I potentially just include the token from Django REST framework's Tokens?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I'm Using Django 1.9 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is something for authenticating users using url get-parameters. AFAIK Django REST framework's Tokens uses HTTP headers for tokens.

You can write your own auth backend, it's quite easy. Here is an example

myproject/setting.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'myproject.backends.UrlTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

myproject/backends.py

```
class UrlTokenBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, token):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(token=token)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if not user.is_active:
            return None

        return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Now when you will call `authenticate` and `login` function Django will check your user against each of your backends. You can manually login user like this (this is view function):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def user_auth(request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    user = authenticate(token=token)
    login(request, user)

    return redirect('index')
```

**Update**

Or you can use [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754980/how-to-manually-authenticate-after-get-django-user) and do only this (without custom backend):

```
def user_auth(request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    user = User.objects.get(token=token)
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    login(request, user)

    return redirect('index')
```