# auto login url for a specific user

Tags: django, django-login

I'm trying to auto login user on the link that I've created, so I'm trying to enable a specific url gateway only for that.

So I have a simple login View:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class SpecialUserGatewayView(View):
    def post(self, request):

        token = request.POST['token']
        user = authenticate(token=token)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_specific_user:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("This user is not Specific User!")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

and the url for this is

`url(r'^special_user/login/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z])/$,', SpecialGatewayView.as_view(), name="special-login")`

Now I'm generating token using [rest framework jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt), and my login url should be something like this `https://mywebpage/special_user/login/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImExQGExc3VwZXJ1c2VyLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYTFAYTFzdXBlcnVzZXIuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTI2MzE5OTk0LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo1Miwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MjYzMTY5OTR9.-pUBVjiAbRhgfuj5IFQP7Qh9KXRX4K_Tyn0nsucF1pM`,

The error is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8888/special_user/login/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImExQGExc3VwZXJ1c2VyLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYTFAYTFzdXBlcnVzZXIuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTI2MzE5OTk0LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo1Miwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MjYzMTY5OTR9.-pUBVjiAbRhgfuj5IFQP7Qh9KXRX4K_Tyn0nsucF1pM/?next=/dashboard/
```

As you can see I'm not sending good url to my application and more, so can someone please help me and explain how can I overcome this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors. First you are trying to log in with a GET method but in your views you use POST method. Second you don't need to create a url for the GET method, you can send GET parameters to any view.

To fix the error change the url to:

```
url(r'^special_user/login', SpecialGatewayView.as_view(), name="special-login")
```

and your view should be something like:

```
class SpecialUserGatewayView(View):
    def get(self, request): # Change to GET

        token = request.GET['token'] # Change to GET
        user = authenticate(token=token)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_specific_user:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("This user is not Specific User!")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: bah, thanks for the explanation, this stuff is clear, was not thinking strait

Comment: One more thing, what about tempering with `ModelBackend`, will that be a better solution in this case, or?

Comment: Yes that would be better, using the JWT(token) is focused only for APIs when you need to send a the token in each request

Comment: but I can make it to go with jwt, yes

Comment: i mean is better using the modelBackend, the jwt(is what you are using) is focused only for APIs

Comment: ok I found something I want, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668282/url-token-authentication-in-django)