# url token authentication is failing to authenticate user

Tags: django

I'm failing to authenticate my user upon the registration. I've found out the solution for one time link token authentication, was tampering with `ModelBackend` you can see the basic solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36670063/4107823), I'll paste up my implementation because I'm using CBV for the view.

Custom `ModelBackend`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
import logging

from business_accounts.models.my_user import MyUser

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class UrlTokenBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Custom login backend that will accept token allow click url login
    """
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(token=token)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            logger.warning('My user=%s does not exist', user)
            return None

        if not user.is_active:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return MyUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            logger.warning('User with this id=%s does not exists', user_id)
            return None
```

The authentication middleware is registered here

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'business_accounts.backends.UrlTokenBackend',
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)
```

Custom view is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import View


    class UrlGatewayLogin(View):
        def get(self, request):
            token = request.GET.get('token')
            user = authenticate(token=token)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('dashboard')
```

and the url is

`url(r'^auth/login/', UrlGatewayLogin.as_view(), name='auth-login')`

Now I'll construct a url for the login, like so, `http:/localhost:8000/auth/login/?token=12323344` so the whole process will just login the user over this link and redirect him to the dashboard.
The login is showing me this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/auth/login/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MjYzNjE5MTksInVzZXJfaWQiOjcwLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFkbWluQGFkbWluLmFpIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbkBhZG1pbi5haSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTI2MzU4OTE5fQ.qyR5SYZ1uO0reVSRjcFdXGGhgfKhdu1eU277UAGU5l8

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.foursquare',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_swagger',
 'django_filters',
 'corsheaders',
 'gunicorn',
 'googleads',
 'django_nose',
 'webpack_loader',
 'common',
 'business_accounts',
 'search',
 'platforms_search',
 'locations',
 'reviews',
 'socialmedia',
 'inbox',
 'stats',
 'usermanagement',
 'connect',
 'dashboard',
 'freetrial',
 'billing',
 'demo',
 'social_tickets',
 'external',
 'test_account']
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/srv/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/srv/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/srv/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/srv/bspotted.net/app/business_accounts/views/url_gateway_login.py" in get
  10.         login(request, user)
File "/srv/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  111.     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
File "/srv/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  226.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /auth/login/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

So can someone explain why is this happening and how can I overcome this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authenticate()` should return user object:

```
class UrlTokenBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Custom login backend that will accept token allow click url login
    """
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(token=token)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            logger.warning('My user=%s does not exist', user)
            return None

        if not user.is_active:
            return None
        return user
```

Comment: sure I've failed to see that, but I'm still receiving the same error

Comment: @PetarP Does user is_active? What `logger.info(user.is_active)` said in `authenticate` method?

Comment: it shows `is_active=True`, I'm a bit confused write now, to be honest

Comment: Ok so `token` will not work, I've managed to login a user using `id` for now, I'll accept this answer because It was helpful